# How do I orient a face so it lays flat?

Tags: faces, transform-orientation

I have a simple flat face. I am looking at the top view and the face is at an arbitrary angle. 
The rotation angles show:
x=0
y=0
z=0

I am used to other programs that would shows the relative angle at all times.
How do I turn this plane so it is aligned with the x or y axis?

Comment: You can align an object to Transform, and if you're using the View orientation that lets you rotate an object to align the view. This question is essentially asking for the opposite. How can you set an object's orientation to match an existing face within that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform displayed is the transform of the **Object**. This particular face has been rotated with respect to object it belongs to, in Edit Mode.

One way to  align the object to its  face, and center it:

- In Edit mode, select the face, and in the Header >Transform Orientations menu, hit the little '+' to create a Custom Orientation from the face.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*
- Object Mode, *Header > Options* menu, check '*Origins*'

[image]

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selected to Cursor*
- *Header > Object > Transform > Align to Tansform Orientation*.

(Uncheck the *Origins* option)

Now if you set the rotation to 0, the object will align to the world, and its face will follow.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Object Mode, Header > Options menu". Could you clarify where this is exactly?

Comment: This is great. I got as far as Object Mode, Header> Options menu? Looking for the options menu. I am using the current build (v2.82a). Almost there! Yes, please clarify.

Comment: @Rekov  see edit..my header is at the bottom, yours might be up top.

Comment: That's so odd. I don't have that button at all. What version Blender are you using?

Comment: It works! Thanks. That seems such a long process. In Rhino you just click the surface and orient it to the surface. It takes a second. I will have to get used to this. I found the options button above the viewport shading on my build (2.82a). Progress....

Comment: If the button doesn't show up, right click on your Header and check 'Show Tool Settings'

Comment: @BillC Phew.. I'm using 2.82(sub7)  was looking for buttons in older builds, etc. It's not so bad, but one thing that annoys me is that Shift-S doesn't respect the alignment settings for the 3D cursor. That would cut steps out. .. If you just want to snap to normal, not  tangent too, that's quicker.. And thanks, Rekov.

Answer (score 1):

Scale it along the x or y axis to 0

Comment: I am not trying to scale it.  Another words from the top view it is at an arbitrary angle and I want it to be aligned either horizontal or vertical

Comment: While this solution isn't bad, here it would cause deformation of the original shape :).

Comment: I need to retain the original scale