# How to correct an object's arbitrary rotation?

Tags: modeling, transforms

One of many 3d modeling "Holy Grails": You get a model from somebody but you are OCD and want to re-align the entire object such that part of such that an edge loop coincides with a plane that is normal to a cardinal axis. Here is an example:

[image]

This is a reimagined enemy called "Chuckya" from Super Mario 64. He has handles that Mario can grab, but they are too high. I want to "reset" the rotation of this object so the selected loop is normal to the XZ-plane (that is, it is rotated such that it is bisected by an axis parallel to the Y-axis). Then I can apply that rotation and rotate it by precise values.

How can this be done without rotating it by eye, which is not nearly as precise as I want? Assume that the current rotation of the object is not known.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183552/how-to-have-an-object-lie-on-a-specific-face

Comment: Thanks batFinger, this didn't come up before